# Windows 2008 - `Where` command shows correct path but the actual command does not work

Tags: windows, command-line, git

On my Windows 2008 VM, I have Git installed. When I run following command

```
where git
```

I get following output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

but when I run `git` on command prompt I get following error

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have confirmed that `git` is included in my `PATH`. Here is what my `PATH`

`PATH=C:\Ruby\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\;C:\Program Files\NCover\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nant-0.91-alpha2\bin;D:\Tools;C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;C:\Windows\system32\dns\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\tools;C:\DevKit;C:\ansi160\x64;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Chocolatey\bin;C:\PhantomJS;C:\Users\suhas.chatekar\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\SystemTools\cmder;`

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Could you please put out your path variable and the command that you are using.

Comment: Does running "git.exe" rather than just "git" make any difference?

Comment: @GauravJoseph Added my `PATH` variable in the original question

Comment: @AndyDavies Running `git.exe` gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote in your path may be the problem.

<strike>I feel that the spaces may be the problem though I can't be sure. There is one thing you can try:</strike>

> Fire up the command prompt
>
> SET PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd" (notice the quotes)
>
> now type git

If all is well then you should move your git to some path with no spaces or simply use inverted commas.

Comment: I guess you mean "quotes" rather than "inverted commas". But that can't be the issue; the paths inside the path variable don't need quotes since they're delimited by `;` rather than space.

Comment: So that seems to work. I have this problem with lot of other commands that are present in the `PATH`. Is there is a better way to fix this?

Comment: @Suhas: have you made sure you've got the right `PATH` variable in your command prompt? Maybe it's somehow overwritten the way you launch the console window? What happens if you run `echo %PATH%` instead of git (in a new console)?

Comment: All Operating Systems have this problem. This is due to a fact that the string after the space is taken to be an argument passed to the supposed program in the first string.

Comment: @Mario Output of `echo %PATH%` is in the original question

Comment: @GauravJoseph But this works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 machine

Comment: Eeks! I have been blind, there is a huge quote in your path line. That may be the problem!

Comment: @GauravJoseph You're right, that's the culprit I guess. Due to this all following path entries are considered to be part of that one (you essentially escape the `;`).

Comment: Bingo. The huge quote was the problem. Removing it has fixed it. If you could add that as a answer I would accept the answer.